# Did finish navigation load multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView to load a URL but my `didFinishNavigation` class multiple times.

I have to evaluate javascript and I had to wait for page to load complete and then have to inject `JS` in it but it fires multiple times.

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation{
    [_webView evaluateJavaScript:js completionHandler:nil];
}
```

`js` is the string in which I have written my JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using UIWebView, after the web view has finished loading, it is calling the delegate method:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
```

Try it.

Comment: I am using `WKWebView` and Objective-C

Comment: OK. Sorry, you've typed 'I am using UIWebView... '